# Bootstrap 2.2.1 modal bug - blue border around calling href?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new here (and also with bootstrap and JavaScript) and hopefully im not asking a question already asked before. I did google plenty and search on here and could not find anyone mentioning this specific problem.

I found a bug I think with Bootstrap 2.2.1 .. when you close a modal, the href link which called it **now has a blue border around it**. This happens with buttons, nav items, anything. This can be seen on the Bootstrap live demo itself - click the blue button "Launch demo modal" under the section "Modals bootstrap-modal.js". You can see a light blue border around the button after closing the modal.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

This issue drove me mad, I messed with the CSS for ages, then tried different browsers, until I downgraded and the issue above is not present on bootstrap 2.0.4.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with 2.2.1 or has it been present since a particular version?, or what the problem is here?

Comment: The same issue continues in bootstrap 3 as well. At least when you open modals by JS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's pretty simple fix once you locate what the CSS property is. I think it came from some issue with the modal's focus and they decided to modify the generated html. You need to define the following CSS. It comes from the following [link](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4511).

```
.modal-open .modal,.btn:focus{
    outline:none!important
}
```

Hope it helps! I made a jsfiddle of the result (including bootstrap's css + js) so you watch a live demo of it, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5sydy/). Note that if you're using something that isn't a button the outline may come back, since we're only applying it there. Since you're referring to a href, it's likely that you're calling the modal from a link, and therefore should also trigger `a:focus`

Comment: Thank you! In my case I had to add a:focus also to that, seems to be sorted now  ! Thanks again!

Comment: Really really helpful. Was looking for a solution like crazy, took me a while to find this, but works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: helped alot! thanx for sharing this. i used it for all buttons as button:focus